# How to fix footer at the bottom of screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I want to fix the footer at the bottom of screen like if the screen height is increase or decrease it comes on the bottom of screen, it never be come shorter then screen height?

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">

<p> <a href="../info/about.php">About </a><a href="../info/help.php">Help </a><a href="../info/terms.php">Terms </a><a href="../info/privacy.php">Privacy </a><a href="../info/advertise.php">Advertise</a><a> - </a>@2016 webste</p>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
background-color:#fafafa;
 text-align: center;
 height:30px;
 margin-top:10%;
}

.footer p {
color: #3c4a50;
line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13.3333px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.footer a {
color: #3c4a50;
text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13.3333px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-right:0.5%;
}

.footer a:hover {
color: #252d31;
font-size:95%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: no it is not my problem solution

Comment: it overflow on the content in the container

Comment: JSFIDDLE:- https://jsfiddle.net/skwcnwwr/

Answer (score 4):

add this css

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: it overflow on the container

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
.footer {
 background-color:#fafafa;
 text-align: center;
 height:30px;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: it overflow on the container

Comment: Can you send me a link on jsfiddle or etc.

Comment: can i send you the whole code of page, html and css

Answer (score 0):

JS fiddle link -

https://jsfiddle.net/e1oywpov/

Just add, position: fixed and bottom:0px, then it will remain in the bottom

```
.footer {
background-color:#fafafa;
 text-align: center;
height:30px;
margin-top:10%;
bottom:0px;
position:fixed
}
```

Comment: it overflow on the container

Comment: it overflow on the container? Can you elaborate this

Answer (score 0):

you can add following CSS & add z-index also

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: it overflow on the container